# Page Size for thesis template

Tags: thesis, paper-size

I have looked at many questions regarding this but none have solved my issue. I am using a template to write my thesis and want to change the size of my paper but am unable to do so with the command:

> \documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

I have tried the following as well

> \usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

but that ends up changing the formatting of the document and puts all the written content to the top left hand of the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  So, you are using a document class named `Thesis`, right?  Clearly, this must be a document class supplied by your university, department, or whatever (`Thesis` does not sound as a name that can be shared worldwide, does it?): this means that someone gave you a file named `Thesis.cls` and instructed you to use that file.  Now, in order to have a chance to answer your question, we need to have access to that file.  Can you post a link to it?  To know exactly what paper size you want to switch to (`letterpaper`? with what margins?) would also help, of course… ;-)

Comment: If you HAVE to use Thesis class, they probably don't want you using letterpaper anyway.

Comment: Sorry, you found one of the worst templates out there. [RUN!](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/)

Comment: I would advice to use [a minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports). But if you really *really* **really** need a template that looks similar to the one you are currently using (which i guess is the one from Sunil, but a link to be sure would be nice), have a look at masters doctoral thesis template on latextemplates.com.

Comment: Yes, it is the one from Sunil. I was able to  figure it out. Essentially I had to delete some setmargin stuff from thesis.cls and then I was able to change the page size to letterpaper.